# ng-selected expression not selecting when true

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, ionic2

When the index of the `accommodation` is `0` then add the selected `attribute` to the option. I am not sure what I am doing wrong.

*The following is the code I am working with*

```
<select formControlName="type" required>
   <option value="{{ accommodation.id }}" *ngFor="let accommodation of ListAccommodationTypes; let i = index;" ng-selected="0 in i">{{ accommodation.name }}</option>
</select>
```

This is what it renders in the DOM

```
<select formcontrolname="type" required="" ng-reflect-name="type" class="ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-invalid">
   <!--template bindings={
      "ng-reflect-ng-for-of": "[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]"
      }-->
   <option ng-selected="0 in i" value="4" ng-reflect-value="4">Something 4</option>
   <option ng-selected="0 in i" value="5" ng-reflect-value="5">Something 5</option>
   <option ng-selected="0 in i" value="3" ng-reflect-value="3">Something 3</option>
   <option ng-selected="0 in i" value="2" ng-reflect-value="2">Something 2</option>
   <option ng-selected="0 in i" value="1" ng-reflect-value="1">Something 1</option>
</select>
```

I have also tried

```
<select formControlName="type" required>
   <option value="{{ accommodation.id }}" *ngFor="let accommodation of ListAccommodationTypes; let i = index;" ng-selected="i==0">{{ accommodation.name }}</option>
</select>

<select formControlName="type" required>
   <option value="{{ accommodation.id }}" *ngFor="let accommodation of ListAccommodationTypes; let i = index;" ng-selected="{{i==0}}">{{ accommodation.name }}</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
<option *ngFor="let accommodation of ListAccommodationTypes; let i = index;"
    [attr.selected]="i == 0 ? true : null">
  {{ accommodation.name }}
</option>
```